# Page output is doubled with HTTP request status on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

When new instance starts on GAE i'm getting doubled render of my page with status string.

Like this
[image: Doubled page output on GAE]

When instance is loaded already everything is ok.

How can i prevent doubled output on instance start?

Code id as simple, as it can be

```
class IndexHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        context = {'message': 'Wellcome to the NailedGames',
                   'page_description': 'Some blabla',
                   'ngames': NGame.all().order('-publish_date')}
        self.render_response('ngames/index.html', **context)
```

And code of BaseHandler

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import jinja2

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        # Returns a Jinja2 renderer cached in the app registry.
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_response(self, _template, **context):
        # Renders a template and writes the result to the response.
        rv = self.jinja2.render_template(_template, **context)
        self.response.write(rv)
```

Comment: Well, it would help to see the code that's generating the page.

Comment: sure, but there is nothing special

Comment: I assume that it has to do something with the @webapp2.cached_property